e4defrag on Raspian cannot run?
Trying this on:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:        9.13
Codename:       stretch

$ uname -a
Linux HOSTNAME 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ e4defrag --version
e4defrag: invalid option -- '-'
Usage   : e4defrag [-v] file...| directory...| device...
        : e4defrag  -c  file...| directory...| device...

This is what mount reports:
$ mount | grep mmc
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)

So, there is a /dev/mmcblk0p2 partition mounted as root of the filesystem /.
Let's try e4defrag, then:
$ sudo e4defrag -cv /
-cv: No such file or directory while trying to open file system: /dev/root

Eh? who said anything about /dev/root?
$ sudo e4defrag -cv /dev/mmcblk0p2
Filesystem is not mounted

What do you mean "not mounted"? Why does mount then say /dev/mmcblk0p2 on / ??
What is going on here; and can I use e4defrag on this system at all, and if so - how?
